# How to tell if file is in internal or external storage?

Tags: android, file

Is there a fail-safe way to tell, given a file path, whether it resides in internal or external storage?

One way would be to see if the external or internal base path is part of the file path, but I'm not sure that's fail-safe.  Maybe it is if converted to canonical form?  But even that's not fail-safe, since converting to canonical form can throw an exception.

Comment: what you mean by internal/external storage ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I think the OP wants to distinguish between RAM and SDCard.